# Bamboo is not running my tests after i renamed the file

Tags: unit-testing, bamboo

We have automatic build and deployment, through Atlassian Bamboo. Tests were configured to run along with that. But I renamed a test file, and now Bamboo is running testless build. How to make bamboo to pick my new test file?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Bamboo, chose the plan that run the test, go to Configuration setting, you have to drill down stages -> jobs ->tasks and look for what tasks are running that test file and make the appropriate change (Probably change the file name there ). Reading the build log might help narrow down the search.